Problem sending json data from js file to .NET controller through ajax post
So, I am trying to get from the client (js) to the server (.net controller) a json string through an ajax post. For some reason, which I cannot understand, it arrives into the controller, but the list is empty (count = 0).

JS Code

    btnAddMovie.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(datesDict);

        var dataToSend = formatDataToSend();
        console.log(dataToSend);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dataToSend));


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SubmitMovieAdd",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    function formatDataToSend() {
        var jsonToSend = [];

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(datesDict)) {
            jsonToSend.push({
                date: key,
                hours: value
            });
        }

        return jsonToSend;
    }

In datesDict (dictionary) there are some values like this:
datesDict = 14/05/2024: ['15:00:00', '12:00:00']
In dataToSend it appears like this:
dataToSend = 0: {date: '14/05/2024', hours: Array(2)}
Final json.stringify => [{"date":"14/05/2024","hours":["15:00:00", "12:00:00"]}]

Controller

    [HttpPost("MyAdminDashBoard/MovieAdd/SubmitMovieAdd")]
    public IActionResult SubmitMovieAdd(List<MovieAddJsonAppModel> json)
    {
        return Content(json.Count().ToString());
    }


Model

    public class MovieAddJsonAppModel
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public List<string> Hours { get; set; }
    }

Can you help me please solve this issue? Thank you:)

Remove contentType: "application/json", from your AJAX call and add dataType: "json"

Ensure that the property names in your C# model match the keys in your JSON object exactly. In your case, the property names should be Date and Hours.
